# Composer PSR-4 class not found

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I have a following directory structure 
[image]

Here is how i used psr-4 in my composer.json file

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"MyMVC\\": "app/"}
},
```

Now in my init file i am trying to load the controllers dynamically like

```
<?php namespace MyMVC;

use MyMVC\Core\Config;
use MyMVC\Controllers;

class Application
{
    /**
     * Takes the arguments and execute the requested route
     *
     * @param  [type] $controller name of the controller
     * @param  [type] $method     name of method
     * @param  array  $arguments  an array of arguments to be passed into method
     * @access private
     */
    private function dispatch($controller, $method, array $arguments)
    {
        $controller = 'Controllers\\' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';
        $controllerObject = new $controller;
    }
```

My `HomeController` looks like this

```
<?php namespace MyMVC\Controllers;

class HomeController
{

    function __construct()
    {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

Now if i get to the url `http://localhost/mymvc/home/bla/bla' I am getting error

```
Fatal error: Class 'Controllers\HomeController' not found in /var/www/html/mymvc/app/init.php on line 136
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Application should be

```
$controller = 'MyMVC\\Controllers\\' . ucfirst($controller) . 'Controller';
```

Comment: Yup that worked. Just to confirm is my implementation of PSR-4 correct ?

Comment: Yes. It is correct. But your folders should be named after the namespaces and you have `MyMVC\Controller`, but your folder is named `controller`, in lowercase. It's working by chance, because php namespaces are case-insensitive.

Comment: And the single backslash is working as well because `\C` is not a escape sequence, so is printed as it is. But if any of your namespaces begins with an escape sequence (example MyMVC`\D`ata) it wont work. http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php. You better always use \\ for namespaces.